# Eclipse C/C++ IDE out of memory

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to use Eclipse C/C++ IDE to read the source code of c++ projects. However, some of my projects are very large, which makes the Eclipse go out of memory when building the index. I tried to adjust the Xmx to 4096m or even larger, but it doesn't make any difference.

How should I deal with it?

Comment: Edited tags. This is about the eclipse IDE, not the C++ language.

Comment: Presumably there is something that is tripping up CDT in this case, if you can reduce it to a submittable bug then it can be addressed. Any chance this is an open source project that someone else can replicate?

Comment: Be sure you're using the latest version of Eclipse (Oxygen), as several OOM bugs have been fixed in recent releases.